# create primary key of differnet columns on mariadb

Tags: python, mariadb

create primary of different columns.
the code below i was able to create primary key of on column. 
i want a primary key of (id, cp, num_lm)

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab1 (id varchar(36) primary key, cp VARCHAR(4), num_lm varchar(55), name int(6), v1 VARCHAR(4), bnp VARCHAR(4));")
```

Thank you in advance,

charles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the primary key instruction at the end:

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab1 (
    id varchar(36),
    cp VARCHAR(4),
    num_lm varchar(55),
    name int(6),
    v1 VARCHAR(4),
    bnp VARCHAR(4),
    PRIMARY KEY (id, cp, num_lm));
""")
```